# How to compare date formats in php? or how to check the date is in what format?

Tags: php, date-format

How to compare date formats in php? For example i have to check either the date is in this format `(21-02-2013)` or in `(21/2/13)`. Please Help

Answer (score 2):

for (21/2/13)

```
   function testDate( $value )   
 {   
  return preg_match( ''^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$'', $value ) )   
 }   

 testDate( '21/11/1999' ); // -> true   
 testDate( '3/9/2008' ); // -> true
```

for (21-02-2013)

```
$d = explode("-"  , $date);
if( !checkdate($d[1], $d[0], $d[2]) )
echo 'Not a recognised date' ;
```

Comment: Thanks! let me check this.